# smart gwt beginner- how to draw image in a draw pane with drawImg.setSrc()

Tags: smartgwt

I am trying to draw an image within a draw pane. This is the code that I am using--

```
                DrawPane drawPane = (DrawPane) event.getSource();  
                DrawImage drawImg = new DrawImage();
                drawImg.setSrc("/other/cokeclassicsm.png");
                //drawImg.setLeft(77);
            //drawImg.setTop(50);
            drawImg.setDrawPane(drawPane);  
            drawImg.draw();
```

But no image is showing on screen--

Now I referred to the Javadoc -- drawImg.setSrc ([this link](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/drawing/DrawImage.html)) and it says that the URL to the image has to be specified...Does this mean I cannot specify a relative path at all?
My image is within war/images/other folder...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

```
DrawImage drawImg = new DrawImage();
// drawImg.setSrc("/other/cokeclassicsm.png"); 
drawImg.setSrc("other/cokeclassicsm.png");
```

Starting a path with "/" with send you to the root of the URL. Starting it without "/" says that you want a relative path to where you are in right now.